# How to sort images into rows in C

Tags: c, sorting

Very simple problem, but can't seem to solve it. I'm probably just not thinking right. So I'm using C and I need to be able to sort some images I download into two rows. Like this: [http://i.imgur.com/lWkEO.png](https://i.imgur.com/lWkEO.png)
So my program will, say, download 30 images and it has to sort it into these two rows just like you see in the picture. So I know I have to loop through them but can't seem to get it.
Can someone please help me out? Like I said I know it's simple but just can't seem to get it to work! Thanks so much! :D

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? How far have you got? Are you able to write the images into a png file yet?

Comment: Ok let me explain more. It's not that I'm having problems with images or anything, just the loop to put them into the rows. So each image is 61x61 and they have 69pixels of vertical and horizontal padding between them. And I just need to get them into two rows (order being ipmortant, 1 then 2 below then 3 next to one as in the image). That's really what my problem is, I can't figure out how to loop it to do this for any amount of images, so let's say I have 30, to do this to 30 of them etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, your loop could either be how Ignacio has done it, or you could do something like this:

```
int i, imageCount, row, col, imagesPerCol;

//...
imagesPerCol = 2;

for(i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
  row = i % imagesPerCol;
  col = i / imagesPerCol;

  //... do image placement here using row and col
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add 2 in your iteration, instead of one, then iterate it again starting from 1 instead of 0.

**EDIT:**

(sigh)

```
void *images;
int NUM_IMAGES = 10;
int NUM_ROWS = 2;

int inneri;
int outeri;

for (outeri = 0; outeri < NUM_ROWS; outeri++)
  for (inneri = outeri; inneri < NUM_IMAGES; inneri += NUM_ROWS)
    do_something_with(images[inneri]);
```

And then if you need an even *bigger* loop around this for some reason, you could use a variable called `thirdi`.

Comment: Wait I dont think I'm understanding what you mean? Could you explain a bit more?